# Clarification on level curves, minum points and points where the level curves are tangent to the constraint set

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose we want to minimize the function: 
$\nu(x_1,x_2) = 9x_1^2 + 4x_2^2 + 12 \rho x_1x_2$,
where $|\rho| \leq 1 $

on the set:
$D:= \{2x_1+x_2 \geq \bar \pi, \ x \geq 0, \ x_1+x_2 = 1\}$, 
where $\bar \pi \in [1,2].$

My professor writes:

> The minimum level curve crossing the region $D$ is an ellipsis tangent
>   to $D$. **If the tangency point $P$ lies in $D$ it will be the minimum
>   point. Otherwise the minimum point will be one of the extreme of $D$**
>   (the one closest to $P$).

If a level curve is tangent to $D$ at the point $P$, how is it possible that $P$ is not in $D$??

Comment: What do you mean by $\rho \leq |1|$? Is $|1| = 1$ ?) Or you just mean $|\rho| \leq 1$?

Comment: You are right. I ve just edited